# Comparing Strings in Arduino C++?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm currently writing some arduino code for a GUI with with Keypad and 16x2 LCD implementation. Part of my program requires a password to be entered before certain content on the Arduino can be accessed, however I can't seem to figure out how to get my saved password and given input to work properly.

```
String pswd = "0000";

char* Input(int Length, byte clmn, byte row) { 
    char output[Length];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Length) {
      char KeyPress = keypad.getKey();
        lcd.setCursor(clmn,row);
        if (KeyPress == '0' || 
            KeyPress == '1' || 
            KeyPress == '2' || 
            KeyPress == '3' || 
            KeyPress == '4' || 
            KeyPress == '5' || 
            KeyPress == '6' || 
            KeyPress == '7' || 
            KeyPress == '8' ||
            KeyPress == '9') {
            output[i] = KeyPress;
            lcd.print(KeyPress);
            i++;
            clmn++; 
            lcd.setCursor(i+1,0);
            lcd.cursor();} 
    }
    delay(3000);
    Serial.println(output);
    return output;
}

bool Is_Psswrd() { 
    bool Passed = false;
    char *Test;
    String test;
    CH2 = true; 
  
    while (CH2) {   
        say("Password: ",0,0);
        Test = Input(4, 10, 0);
        test = Test;
        if (test==pswd) {
            Passed = true;
            CH2 = false; }
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                lcd.clear();
                say("Incorrect ",0,0);
                delay(200); } } 
    }
    return Passed;

}   

void setup() {
  Is_Psswrd();
  
}

void loop() {}
```

I've tried alot of different things for saving, inputting, and checking characters, some more jankier than others. My original plan was to save all variables as char* variables and use the strcmp() function, but that didn't seem to work (strcmp() kept outputting "144") and I learned I needed const char* to make the function work properly. I've given the code I believe is needed to access the issue, but if you need the rest of the code I can paste it.

I am very new to C++. Most of my code is written in Java. Can someone please explain what needs to be done to get two char*/strings to compare in the way I want. I am open to fully rewriting my functions I just need to get this implemented.

Comment: OT: `test = Test` this is perfectly unreadable. Don't use identifiers that only differ by case

Comment: The issue here doesn't seem to be string comparison. The issue seems to be embedded systems asynchronous input. The first problem appears to be that you're freezing `setup()` waiting for user input.

Comment: To use `strcmp()`, you need to make sure your c-strings are null terminated. You can use the Arduino `String` object otherwise https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

Comment: I still don't understand what are you asking about. In Arduino you can compare `String` objects using the usual comparison `operator==`, you don't even need any `strcmp`. In the pasted code which part is the problematic one? Why `char* Input(int Length, byte clmn, byte row)` instead of just `String Input(int Length, byte clmn, byte row)` ? If you return the pointer to local stack variable it gets invalidated on function return.

Comment: In the function `Input(...)` you are returning a pointer to an automatic variable (it goes out of scope when the function returns).  That won't work.  You _could_  fix this by moving `char output[Length];` to global scope (top of the file), and not returning anything from `Input`.

Comment: `char output[Length];` -- This isn't valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time value, not a runtime value.  I would suggest using `String` throughout the code, and minimize, if not drop altogether, explicit usage of `char *`.

Comment: The variable `output` is destroyed when the function `Input` returns. Therefore its stack memory can get reused for another variable - like the variables inside `strcmp`. This might explain some of your problems.

Comment: Akso: [`isDigit`](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/characters/isdigit/) exists.

Comment: I'm going to be that guy and just say that string comparison for password verification is a terrible idea, even for a toy project.

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks like an attempt of using one of the most difficult languages out there, C++, as a tool to do "cool stuff", all without learning C++ properly.  That usually doesn't end too well.  There are basic fundamental mistakes being made in the code, mistakes that wouldn't occur with an experienced C++ programmer (or one that has gone through learning the basics of C++).

Comment: In embedded systems, you want to stay away from dynamic memory allocation.  Use a large fixed size.  The problem with dynamic memory allocation is fragmentation.  Fragmentation is evil with embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

If 4 character hard coded "password" is fine, String objects are too much overhead, IMO.
Here's demo code with a 3x4 keypad and a 16x2 display via I2C:

```
#include <LCD_I2C.h>
LCD_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);

#include <Keypad.h>
const uint8_t ROWS = 4;
const uint8_t COLS = 3;
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  { '1', '2', '3' },
  { '4', '5', '6' },
  { '7', '8', '9' },
  { '*', '0', '#' }
};

uint8_t colPins[COLS] = { 4, 3, 2 }; 
// Pins connected to     C1, C2, C3
uint8_t rowPins[ROWS] = { 8, 7, 6, 5 }; 
// Pins connected to     R1, R2, R3, R4
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);


const byte OFFS =4; // position on lcd
byte pos=0;   // 0...3

void setup() {
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("PWD:");

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("keypad with lcd");
}
char pwd[5]; // 4 digits + '\0'

bool check (const char* pwd) {
  return (strcmp(pwd, "1234")==0);
}

void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key != NO_KEY) {
    // Serial.println(key);
    lcd.write(key);
    if (pos < 4) pwd[pos++] = key;
    if (pos == 4) {
      bool result = check(pwd);
      if (result == false) {
        pos = 0;
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Wrong pwd");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("PWD:    ");
        lcd.setCursor(OFFS,1);
      } else if (pos == 4) {
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Hooray    ");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        pos++; 
      } // else continue writing to bottom line 
    }
  }
}
```